# Git submodule preventing checkout (working directory is clean)?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a git project set up, with a superproject (let's call it `suppy`) and a subproject (let's call it `subby`). The branches of the project are seen below.

```
suppy
    -master
    -other

subby
    -master
```

The directory structure is:

```
suppy
    subby
```

I'm currently on branch `other`, an I'd like to checkout back to `suppy`'s `master`. When I try, I get a git error saying that all the files in the submodule are untracked working tree files and would be overwritten by checkout. How do I resolve this so `subby`'s files aren't blocking my path to `suppy`'s master?

I'm in suppy, and running git status returns "nothing to commit, working directory clean". What's going on?

Comment: Can you verify if you are on correct repository? :s

Comment: @e.doroskevic How would I do that?

Comment: Check which directory you are in

Comment: @e.doroskevic I'm in suppy

Comment: In `suppy`'s master branch, is there a directory named `subby`? That would prevent a checkout if the submodule `subby` is only in `other` branch.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and found a way to get out of it. I did `git checkout -f master`. However at first it complained about a file that I had changed but had run `git update-index --assume-unchanged [filename]` on it previously. So I did a checkout on this file and then was finally able to checkout to the master branch with `checkout -f master`.

It made a bit of a mess in the submodules but with a combination of pulling from upstream, multiple submodule updates, checkouts on certain submodule folders and simply erasing some offending submodule folders I was able to get my master branch clean.